# MySQL display incorrect data from row

Tags: php, mysql

Why mysql display incorrect data
in database

```
-------------------
|     Product     |
-------------------
| id              |
| name            |
| options_id      |
-------------------
```

Database row

```
id = 1,
name = Ring,
options_id = 2,5,6,1,
```

SQL Command

```
SELECT options_id FROM product WHERE name='Ring'
```

When am i test on phpMyAdmin => 2,5,6,1, Correct
But PHP

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT options_id FROM product WHERE name='Ring'");
$arrProduct = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $arrProduct['options_id'];
```

Result = 1,

Comment: That's because you're just fetching the first row. Loop the fetch, and you'll get them all. See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: my database have one row

Comment: try `var_dump($arrProduct['options_id']);`

Comment: try id "var_dump" result = string(2)

Comment: Your php code and your phpMyAdmin are using different servers or a different database.